# How to retrieve the seller_receivable_breakdown values?

Tags: javascript, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need help with finding a way to get the seller_receivable_breakdown values (gross_amount, paypal_fee, net_amount) from Paypal v2 Api in the sandbox

Here is my code:

```
            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                    alert('paypal fees: ' + details.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].seller_receivable_breakdown.paypal_fee.value);
                });
            },
```

I followed the documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2#captures_get

And I managed to get other fields such as:

```
details.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].status
details.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id
```

but I couldn't get the seller_receivable_breakdown values. any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you printed out the entire object? Use `console.log()`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried to print the object out and I found that the **seller_receivable_breakdown fields** aren't there as they should even thought that the documentations says that they should be in the purchase_units >> payments >> captures array. I wonder why

Comment: `purchase_units: Array(1)
0:
amount: {value: "100.99", currency_code: "SEK"}
payee: {email_address: "blablabla@gmail.com", merchant_id: "D8AOYHUX2L75G"}
payments:
captures: Array(1)
0:
amount: {value: "100.99", currency_code: "SEK"}
create_time: "2020-11-24T08:56:04Z"
final_capture: true
id: "1VE71745JL288960Y"
links: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
seller_protection: {status: "NOT_ELIGIBLE"}
status: "COMPLETED"
update_time: "2020-11-24T08:56:04Z"`

Answer (score 0):

From the shared log:

> purchase_units: Array(1) 0: amount: {value: "100.99", currency_code: "SEK"} payee: {email_address: "blablabla@gmail.com", merchant_id: "D8AOYHUX2L75G"} payments: captures: Array(1) 0: amount: {value: "100.99", currency_code: "SEK"} create_time: "2020-11-24T08:56:04Z" final_capture: true id: "1VE71745JL288960Y" links: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] seller_protection: {status: "NOT_ELIGIBLE"} status: "COMPLETED" update_time: "2020-11-24T08:56:04Z"

Note `payee: {email_address: "blablabla@gmail.com"`

There is no breakdown because no PayPal transaction exists yet, this order is completed but was sent to a payee email with no account, and so the payment has not (yet) been accepted.

If the payment is not accepted within 30 days, it will be returned to the sender.

Comment: This is not the email that was used. I just replaced it now when I commented the code here. I have used another email that is verified, my personal email

Comment: This appears to be sandbox. Whatever email you used does not appear to correspond to a sandbox account that can receive payments. The fact that your email corresponds to an account in the live environment is of no relevance.

Comment: If I understood you right, the email that I used is the same email that I used in the sandbox account app ( and It is a real email, as I mentioned above). I can also see that the payment has went through without a problem in the sanbox.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be a matter of `"seller_receivable_breakdown"` not being implemented in the sandbox environment.  It will be there for live transactions